# How to show the vertical data horizentally through sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

my table has two column columnname and data

i issue a simple sql like `select * from mytable` then data is showing like

```
colname               data
-------------------   -----------
JID                   41185
WID                   0
AccountReference      LH169
OEReference           Ari002
InvoiceNumber         0
```

but i want to display data in different way like

```
JID     WID    AccountReference   OEReference     InvoiceNumber
41185   0      LH169              Ari002          0
```

if i need to show data horizentally then what sql i need to issue..........please help.

Comment: Where are you issuing the `select` statement? SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  JID,WID,AccountReference,OEReference,InvoiceNumber
FROM    
( 
    SELECT colname, data FROM YourTableName
) 
p 
PIVOT 
( 
    Max(data) FOR colname 
    IN ([JID],[WID],[AccountReference],[OEReference],[InvoiceNumber])
) AS pvt
```

you can try below links. contains tutorials for the usage of Pivot.

[Link1](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx)

[Link2](http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/04/12/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx)

Comment: First I've heard of Pivot - thanks. Is it available in anything other than MQ SQLServer 2005?  My google-fu is failing

Comment: If you are talking about 2008 then Yes

Comment: Sorry, I know MS Sql server only. :)

Comment: @Wudang - It's also supported by [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm)

Comment: why Max() function is used here.

Comment: In order to show the data in pivot part, aggregate function must be used.

Comment: @Thomas - because the syntax is defined to require an aggregate function, because, in general, there's no guarantee that there's only a single row with `colname='AccountReference'`.

Comment: Cool - I use MS and Sybase mainly.  I'll have a dig

Answer (score 4):

SQL isn't really about display.  The problem you have is that you'd really need 2 queries (1 for colname and 1 for data) with no guarantee the data would be returned in the same order for each query.  You really need to wrap some external code around this - save the query results in a 2-d array of string (or a collection etc) then iterate through each

Answer (score 1):

If the values of `colname` are known in advance & unique;

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
PIVOT (
    MAX(data) 
    FOR colname in ([JID],[WID],[AccountReference],[OEReference],[InvoiceNumber])
) pv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find this in my blog:
http://sql-tricks.blogspot.com/2011/04/sql-server-rows-transpose.html

You should change @xml variable like this:

```
SET @xml = ( SELECT colname,data,
                Row_Number() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT   1
                                             ) ) Rn
         FROM   mytable
       FOR
         XML PATH('Row') ,
             ROOT('Root') ,
             ELEMENTS XSINIL
       ) ;
```